# What are the possible commands to reset a wifi connection?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I am affected by the bug that occasionally my wifi connection is broken on resume from suspend. The problem manifests as follows:

**Screenshot:**

[image]

What are possible commands I can try to run from the command-line to reset my wifi connection without having to restart my system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo gedit  /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. A new empty file will open. Add the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Proofread carefully twice, save and close the text editor. Now do:

```
sudo chmod +x  /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
```

And next:

```
sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
```

Reboot and let us know if the problem is solved.

Comment: Does this depend on `systemd | upstart`?

Comment: I am asking because I have this problem too, but I have 14.04 with upstart.

Comment: This is the *systemd* method.

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04. Anyway, before applying this new service, it is advisable to first run `/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service` natively in the shell and see if it helps. If not, this extra service does neither.

Comment: This did not work for me on 18.04.

Comment: @RussellRichie I suggest that you start your own new question.

Answer (score 0):

The command is

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
dhclient wlan0
```