# Ubuntu 16.04LTS wifi not restarting after suspend

Tags: wireless, 16.04, suspend

I know this has been discussed here previously, because I've googled it many times and I've tried a good chunk of the workarounds that people have suggested, included restarting the network manager, and a few scripts, including creating a config file and doing SUSPEND_MODULES for my wireless card, but still no dice, so now i'm trying to crowdsource :)  Has anyone also not had any luck with the solutions provided?  And found a workaround?  I haven't tried installing a new kernel yet fwiw...anyway device info below:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:29:af:6f:bf:74
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.4.0-38-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:53 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c3100000-c3103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: d0:bf:9c:88:a4:e8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3004000-c3004fff memory:c3000000-c3003fff
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE for any help that can be provided!

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://askubuntu.com/questions/741620/what-are-the-possible-commands-to-reset-a-wifi-connection/741626#741626

Comment: I had not actually tried that one, but I did just try it, and it sadly didn't work either...i did copy and paste what needed to go into the wifi-resume file into a new file (i also didn't have a wifi-resume file in that directory at all), and followed the rest of the directions :)  Soooo yeah :)  Thank you for your super fast reply!!

Comment: Did you try 'gedit /var/log/syslog' position to time of resume and look for error messages? Under systemd you should see wpa-supplicant or something like that being called. I'm on my phone.

Comment: I did just look and I see it complaining about a return code of 255 when trying to start wpasupplicant:

Comment: I hit enter too soon:  systemd-sleep[3185]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Sep 25 14:18:36 lara-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started Suspend.

Comment: I updated to yakety yak and the wifi still doesn't reconnect after being suspended, does anyone else see this behavior still?